# Around Advice for methods on Interface

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to add an `around` advice on methods declared in an interface.

My package structure is as follows:

- sample
- sample.ifaces( this package has SampleInterface which has method declared sampleOperation)
- sample.ifaces.impl(this package has SampleImplementation which implements sampleOperation)
- sample.aspect(class SampleAspect)

In SampleAspect I am trying to add around advice

```
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class SampleAspect {
        //@Pointcut("execution(public * sample.ifaces.impl.SampleImplementation .*(..))")
        //@Pointcut("within(sample.ifaces.SampleInterface+) && execution(* sample*(..))")
        //@Pointcut("execution(public * sample.ifaces.SampleInterface+.sample*(..))")
        //@Pointcut("execution(* sample.ifaces.SampleInterface.*(..))")
        //@Pointcut("execution(* sample.ifaces.SampleInterface+.*(..))")
        @Pointcut("execution(* sample.ifaces.SampleInterface.sample*(..))")
        public void retry() {
        }

        @Around("retry()")
        private void retryHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
            Object o = null;
            try {
                logger.info("before exec");
                o = pjp.proceed();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("exception in exev");
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                logger.error("unknown");
            }
        }
}
```

I tried many combinations to make it work but its not working. I need to have Pointcut defined for method SampleOperation at interface level and the when the implemented method executes via super-class reference, the advice should get executed.

** UPDATE **

I analysed this further. My new package structure is:

- sample
- sample.config(This package has ConfigBean which is defined in appContext.xml as bean)
- sample.ifaces( this package has SampleInterface which has method declared sampleOperation)
- sample.ifaces.impl(this package has SampleImplementation which implements   sampleOperation)
- sample.aspect(class SampleAspect defined in App context as bean )

`ConfigBean` bean is initialized from appContext. 
The initialize method contains code to initialize `SampleInterface` reference.

`SampleInterface` is not a spring bean.

I tried various combinations on this. When I use

```
@Pointcut("within( sample.config.*)") //-> Does work
```

When I use

```
@Pointcut("within( sample.ifaces.*)")  //-> Does not work
```

Execution point-cuts do not work for me. They simply compile successfully but do not get called.

Comment: For starters your `@Around` method is wrong. It must always return Object and you should always return the result. Something like `execution(* sample.ifaces.SampleInterface+.*(..))` should do the trick. Also are you sure your aspect is applied in your configuration?

Comment: added further exaplanation to the problem.

Comment: What I don't get do you want to do something with a spring managed bean or not. If not it is never going to work as it will only work for sprnig managed bean unless you use something like loadtime or compile timeweaving.

Comment: You mean to say that Advices and PointCuts will only work on classes which are managed by Spring. They do not scan the package completely.

Comment: That depends on what you use. When using loadtime or compile timeweaving it doesn't matter. When using spring and its default mechanism (proxies) it only works for spring managed beans.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the below pointcut expression. I just tried it with an interface and a method within it and it worked for me.

`within` because , it limits matching to join points within certain types (simply the execution of a method declared within a matching type when using Spring AOP)

and then

`execution`, since i want this to be executed only on the update() method

```
within(sample.ifaces.SampleInterface+) && execution(* sample(..))
```

Comment: I got it. I was not defining the class as a bean. I was expecting PointCut to scan through the whole code-base. It scans only through those classes and implementations of interfaces, which are declared as managed beans in Spring.