# Are `Point-Cuts` and `Advices` only applicable to beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I posted following question for which I am still looking an answer.

[Around Advice for methods on Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166293/around-advice-for-methods-on-interface)

While looking in to this another question has come to my mind:

- Are `Point-Cuts` and `Advices` only applicable to the classes which are declared as bean in spring's appContext.xml
- Are `Point-Cuts` and `Advices` Is not applicable to all classes in the code-base ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the Spring AOP documentation. THe documentation does say that Spring AOP is only for `method execution join points(advising the execution of methods on Spring beans)`

### 6.1.2. Spring AOP capabilities and goals

> Spring AOP is implemented in pure Java. There is no need for a special
>   compilation process. Spring AOP does not need to control the class
>   loader hierarchy, and is thus suitable for use in a J2EE web container
>   or application server. Spring AOP currently supports only method
>   execution join points (advising the execution of methods on Spring
>   beans). Field interception is not implemented, although support for
>   field interception could be added without breaking the core Spring AOP
>   APIs. If you need to advise field access and update join points,
>   consider a language such as AspectJ. Spring AOP's approach to AOP
>   differs from that of most other AOP frameworks. The aim is not to
>   provide the most complete AOP implementation (although Spring AOP is
>   quite capable); it is rather to provide a close integration between
>   AOP implementation and Spring IoC to help solve common problems in
>   enterprise applications. Thus, for example, the Spring Framework's AOP
>   functionality is normally used in conjunction with the Spring IoC
>   container. Aspects are configured using normal bean definition syntax
>   (although this allows powerful "autoproxying" capabilities): this is a
>   crucial difference from other AOP implementations. There are some
>   things you cannot do easily or efficiently with Spring AOP, such as
>   advise very fine-grained objects (such as domain objects typically):
>   AspectJ is the best choice in such cases. However, our experience is
>   that Spring AOP provides an excellent solution to most problems in
>   J2EE applications that are amenable to AOP.